# Separating Backcbone and Detector for DeformableDETR

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection

Basing myself on [this](https://github.com/fundamentalvision/Deformable-DETR) repository, I'm trying to separate the backbone (ResNet-50) and detector (Deformable DETR), so that later I can work on some modification more easily. As such, my backbone does not utilizes NestedTensor used in the repository and the output features from it are converted to NestedTensor when received by the Deformable DETR.
A few modifications were made on the Deformable DETR side:

- Backbone is not received as parameter in init, only a list containing the output channels for each feature level;
- Transformer is not received as parameter in init, for simplicity, right now the transformer is always built using build_deforamble_transformer directly inside init;
- forward receives x and features, x is the original input before the backbone, features are the outputs from the backbone;
- the condition for if self.num_feature_levels > len(srcs) was removed as it is guarateed for now boths value are the same;

When receiving a (2x3x69x69) x dummy input (filled with ones) I get an error at tmp[..., :2] += reference: `RuntimeError: output with shape [100, 2] doesn't match the broadcast shape [2, 100, 2]`. I do not understand why.

My features have all expected shapes:

- 0 torch.Size([2, 64, 69, 69])
- 1 torch.Size([2, 256, 69, 69])
- 2 torch.Size([2, 512, 35, 35])
- 3 torch.Size([2, 1024, 18, 18])
- 4 torch.Size([2, 2048, 9, 9])

Below is the DeformableDETR class as modified with documentation and comments removed for compacting.

```py
class DeformableDETR(BaseDetector):
    def __init__(self, channels, num_feature_levels, num_classes, num_queries,
                 aux_loss=True, with_box_refine=False, two_stage=False, **kwargs):
        args = kwargs.pop('args')
        hidden_dim = kwargs.pop('hidden_dim')
        position_embedding = kwargs.pop('position_embedding')
        super(DeformableDETR, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.position_encoding = build_position_encoding(hidden_dim, position_embedding)

        self.num_queries = num_queries
        transformer = build_deforamble_transformer(args=args)
        self.transformer = transformer
        hidden_dim = transformer.d_model
        self.class_embed = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, num_classes)
        self.bbox_embed = MLP(hidden_dim, hidden_dim, 4, 3)
        self.num_feature_levels = num_feature_levels
        if not two_stage:
            self.query_embed = nn.Embedding(num_queries, hidden_dim*2)
        if num_feature_levels > 1:
            num_backbone_outs = len(channels)
            input_proj_list = []
            for _ in range(num_backbone_outs):
                in_channels = channels[_]
                input_proj_list.append(nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Conv2d(in_channels, hidden_dim, kernel_size=1),
                    nn.GroupNorm(32, hidden_dim),
                ))
            for _ in range(num_feature_levels - num_backbone_outs):
                input_proj_list.append(nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Conv2d(in_channels, hidden_dim, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
                    nn.GroupNorm(32, hidden_dim),
                ))
                in_channels = hidden_dim
            self.input_proj = nn.ModuleList(input_proj_list)
        else:
            self.input_proj = nn.ModuleList([
                nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Conv2d(channels[0], hidden_dim, kernel_size=1),
                    nn.GroupNorm(32, hidden_dim),
                )])
        self.aux_loss = aux_loss
        self.with_box_refine = with_box_refine
        self.two_stage = two_stage

        prior_prob = 0.01
        bias_value = -math.log((1 - prior_prob) / prior_prob)
        self.class_embed.bias.data = torch.ones(num_classes) * bias_value
        nn.init.constant_(self.bbox_embed.layers[-1].weight.data, 0)
        nn.init.constant_(self.bbox_embed.layers[-1].bias.data, 0)
        for proj in self.input_proj:
            nn.init.xavier_uniform_(proj[0].weight, gain=1)
            nn.init.constant_(proj[0].bias, 0)

        num_pred = (transformer.decoder.num_layers + 1) if two_stage else transformer.decoder.num_layers
        if with_box_refine:
            self.class_embed = _get_clones(self.class_embed, num_pred)
            self.bbox_embed = _get_clones(self.bbox_embed, num_pred)
            nn.init.constant_(self.bbox_embed[0].layers[-1].bias.data[2:], -2.0)
            # hack implementation for iterative bounding box refinement
            self.transformer.decoder.bbox_embed = self.bbox_embed
        else:
            nn.init.constant_(self.bbox_embed.layers[-1].bias.data[2:], -2.0)
            self.class_embed = nn.ModuleList([self.class_embed for _ in range(num_pred)])
            self.bbox_embed = nn.ModuleList([self.bbox_embed for _ in range(num_pred)])
            self.transformer.decoder.bbox_embed = None
        if two_stage:
            self.transformer.decoder.class_embed = self.class_embed
            for box_embed in self.bbox_embed:
                nn.init.constant_(box_embed.layers[-1].bias.data[2:], 0.0)

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor, features: List[torch.Tensor], *args):
        out = []
        pos = []

        for f in features:
            nested_x = nested_tensor_from_tensor_list(f)
            mask = F.interpolate(nested_x.mask[None].float(), size=f.shape[-2:]).to(torch.bool)[0]
            out.append(NestedTensor(f, mask))
            pos.append(self.position_encoding(out[-1]).to(out[-1].tensors.dtype))

        srcs = []
        masks = []
        for l, feat in enumerate(out):
            src, mask = feat.decompose()
            srcs.append(self.input_proj[l](src))
            masks.append(mask)
            assert mask is not None
        
        query_embeds = None
        if not self.two_stage:
            query_embeds = self.query_embed.weight
        hs, init_reference, inter_references, enc_outputs_class, enc_outputs_coord_unact = self.transformer(srcs, masks, pos, query_embeds)
        
        outputs_classes = []
        outputs_coords = []
        for lvl in range(len(features)):
            print(lvl, features[lvl].shape)
        for lvl in range(hs.shape[0]):
            if lvl == 0:
                reference = init_reference
            else:
                reference = inter_references[lvl - 1]
            reference = inverse_sigmoid(reference)
            outputs_class = self.class_embed[lvl](hs[lvl])
            tmp = self.bbox_embed[lvl](hs[lvl])
            if reference.shape[-1] == 4:
                tmp += reference
            else:
                tmp[..., :2] += reference # <<< ERROR happens here
            outputs_coord = tmp.sigmoid()
            outputs_classes.append(outputs_class)
            outputs_coords.append(outputs_coord)
        outputs_class = torch.stack(outputs_classes)
        outputs_coord = torch.stack(outputs_coords)

        out = {'pred_logits': outputs_class[-1], 'pred_boxes': outputs_coord[-1]}
        if self.aux_loss:
            out['aux_outputs'] = self._set_aux_loss(outputs_class, outputs_coord)

        if self.two_stage:
            enc_outputs_coord = enc_outputs_coord_unact.sigmoid()
            out['enc_outputs'] = {'pred_logits': enc_outputs_class, 'pred_boxes': enc_outputs_coord}
        return out
```